# c++ segfault when accessing array

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I wanted to check something about access violation so I wrote down this code:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
for(int i=0; i < 20000; i++) {
    cout << i << ": " << a[i] << endl;
}
```

It crashes, as it should.

Now, this code should segfault because 20000 is too high and I getting beyond my address space, correct?

What I don't get is why it segfaults on different `i`. Each time I run this code I get segfault on different location. Is that because my array was allocated in a different place on the stack and got more or less address space than before?

Comment: It yields undefined behavior. Don't bother attempting to investigate this behavior, because it might be different on different platforms (and even on the same platform, on each execution).

Comment: @barakmanos I want to understand the principal. This should crash because of an access violation. Are the "restricted" areas in the memory change between two consecutive runs? or is my array changes it's location?

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong... but I believe your program can access any address the system allocates to it. If you go beyond the array bounds and it still is your programs memory, it won't seg fault. It will seg fault when you go out of bounds. So perhaps coincidentally sometimes you have memory lined up beyond the array's bounds.

Comment: The C/C++ language standards do not define where and how each memory segment is allocated. This is up to compiler implementation, which in turn depends on (or is designated for) the underlying HW architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stack is allocated somewhere. You have no idea how far it is from your stack the nearest memory address that you cannot read.

Comment: Except you know you cannot read `a[i]` if `i > 2` (or `i < 0`).

Comment: This is speculating what triggers the access violation. A not unreasonable speculation but still speculation.